# Best practice to handle the ids of objects from database in application

Tags: android, sqlite

A practical example of this problem: I have a `Player` object which is stored in the database and has an id attribute which is its primary key. The `Player` object will have an id attribute in the application too of course, because I need it to interact with the database. On the startup of the app, the players are retrieved from the database and their id is set. But, if I create a new `Player`, I need to set a new id to him, which should be the max id value in the database + 1. What's the best way of managing this id thing?

My way of doing this is keeping a `static int` counter in the `Player` class, which is initialized at the start of the app. Then, when an object is created, its id is set with the value of that counter + 1.

Comment: Is that database used by more than one instance of the app at the same time? Because if so, think of what would happen when two instances are initialized with the same counter value.

Comment: no of course not, it's not a "shared" database, there is no concurrency problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) the new player into the database, you get the _id/rowid back as the insert's return value.